# Inputting and Displaying data

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

I need to enter three details of 3 movies and then get them to display, some of the questions asked won't let me enter data into them and the data that displays only contains one word.

Here's the assignment question:

Write appropriate getter and setter methods for each of the private data members and
you should also write an appropriate constructor Your application should include a tester/driver
class, which creates three instances of the Movie class and stores them in an array. Your tester
class should use a for loop to set the title, genre and rating of the Movie objects. You should
also use a for loop you should traverse the array and display the title, genre and rating for each
element of the array and call the playIt() method for each object.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code and also if it's not too much to ask could you show me how to use arrays and a for loop. I'm using eclipse.

the driver class

```
class Movie {

    //private instances
    private String title = "unassigned";
    private String genre = "unassigned";
    private int rating = 0;

    void playIt() {
        System.out.println(" - Now Playing");
    }

    //getters
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getGenre(){
        return genre;
    }

    public int getRating(){
        return rating;
    }

    //setters
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre){
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}//end class
```

the tester

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Movie_Tester {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Movie one = new Movie();
        Movie two = new Movie();
        Movie three = new Movie();

        //declare variables
        String title1, title2, title3;
        String genre1, genre2, genre3;
        int rating1, rating2, rating3;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter Details For Movie 1
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Title Of Movie 1: ");
        title1 = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Genre Of Movie 1: ");
        genre1 = user_input.next();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Rating Of Movie 1: ");
        rating1 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");

        //Enter Details For Movie 2
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Title Of Movie 2: ");
        title2 = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Genre Of Movie 2: ");
        genre2 = user_input.next();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Rating Of Movie 2: ");
        rating2 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");

        //Enter Details For Movie 3
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Title Of Movie 3: ");
        title3 = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Genre Of Movie 3: ");
        genre3 = user_input.next();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Rating Of Movie 3: ");
        rating3 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");

        //Set data for Movie one
        one.setTitle(title1);
        one.setGenre(genre1);
        one.setRating(rating1); 
        one.playIt();

        //Print data to screen
        System.out.println("Movie 1 Title = : " + one.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Movie 1 Genre = : " + one.getGenre());
        System.out.println("Movie 1 Rating = : " + one.getRating());        
        System.out.println(" ");

        //Set data for Movie two
        two.setTitle(title2);
        two.setGenre(genre2);
        two.setRating(rating2);
        two.playIt();

        //Print data to screen
        System.out.println("Movie 2 Title = : " + two.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Movie 2 Genre = : " + two.getGenre());  
        System.out.println("Movie 2 Rating = : " + two.getRating());        
        System.out.println(" ");

        //Set data for Movie three
        three.setTitle(title3);
        three.setGenre(genre3);
        three.setRating(rating3);
        three.playIt();

        //Print data to screen
        System.out.println("Movie 3 Title = : " + three.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Movie 3 Genre = : " + three.getGenre());    
        System.out.println("Movie 3 Rating = : " + three.getRating());  
        input.close();
        user_input.close();
        userInput.close();
        System.out.println(" ");


    }//end main method
}//end class
```

When I run it this is what I get:

```
Please Enter The Title Of Movie 1: 
Step Brothers

Please Enter The Genre Of Movie 1: 
Comedy

Please Enter The Rating Of Movie 1: 
4

Please Enter The Title Of Movie 2: 

Please Enter The Genre Of Movie 2: 
Crime Comedy

Please Enter The Rating Of Movie 2: 
4

Please Enter The Title Of Movie 3: 
O Brother, Where Art Thou?

Please Enter The Genre Of Movie 3: 

Please Enter The Rating Of Movie 3: 
5

 - Now Playing

Movie 1 Title = : Step

Movie 1 Genre = : Comedy

Movie 1 Rating = : 4

 - Now Playing

Movie 2 Title = : Brothers

Movie 2 Genre = : Crime

Movie 2 Rating = : 4

 - Now Playing

Movie 3 Title = : O

Movie 3 Genre = : Comedy

Movie 3 Rating = : 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that `next()` method of `Scanner` only gets the next token, not the whole line. You want the `nextLine()` method.

I don't know if you have gotten to this in your class yet, but usually you want to use `Scanner` with a try-with-resources block. This will ensure that no matter what, your `Scanner` objects are closed (it's syntactic sugar for closing them in a `finally` block).

You also don't need a separate scanner for each input, although because you are going to need both `readLine()` and `nextInt()`, you do need two of them (`Scanner` has issues if you try to `readLine()` after using `nextInt()`).

You also are doing things the hard way by not using loops. When you use a for loop, the code is much simpler and shorter. Your teacher is asking you to use arrays and for loops without explaining to you how to use them? Isn't there a textbook or some class notes you can reference?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MovieTester {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Movie[] movies = new Movie[3];

        try (Scanner string_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner int_input = new Scanner(System.in);) // Try with resources
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Movie movie = new Movie();

                // Enter Details For Movie
                System.out.println("Please Enter The Title Of Movie: ");
                movie.setTitle(string_input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Please Enter The Genre Of Movie: ");
                movie.setGenre(string_input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Please Enter The Rating Of Movie: ");
                movie.setRating(int_input.nextInt());
                System.out.println();

                movies[i] = movie;
            }

            // Play Movies
            for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
                Movie movie = movies[i];

                System.out.println("Title: " + movie.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Genre: " + movie.getGenre());
                System.out.println("Rating: " + movie.getRating());
                movies[i].playIt();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }//end main method
}//end class
```